# How can I tell what app, script, or service is responsible for changing resolv.conf?

Tags: dns, vpn, resolv.conf, resolvconf

I am aware that DNS and other name resolution is controlled most proximately by /etc/resolv.conf, and that resolvconf / resolvectl / systemd-resolve is most proximately responsible for the contents of resolv.conf... but **is there a way to know what is making that change via resolvconf?**

When I boot my computer, resolv.conf is configured as it should be. Then I use a specific VPN client (openfortivpn), and while VPNd there are new lines using both the nameserver and search directives. But then when I un-VPN via ctrl-C, the nameserver lines go back to their correct value but the search line retains its incorrect value. resolvconf -u does not fix this. I can only assume openfortivpn isn't cleaning up after itself for some reason, and I'd like to be able to clean up after it myself.

openfortivpn does not change resolvconv's head or tail files.

Thanks very much for your time. I am sure I am missing something very basic, so I'd also like to thank you ahead of time for your patience.

EDIT: Ubuntu version 20.04

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: I'm not an expert on it, but `cat /etc/resolv.conf` brings up `systemd-resolved` as a potential suspect, in the first line... Then here's the arch wiki on it (arch wikis are usually good): https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-resolved (if I was wrong, then sorry for sending you on a false trip) This manual: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/systemd-resolved.service.8.html points at `/lib/systemd/systemd-resolved` (... cool, it does not exist on my Ubuntu 20.04!) (Then I'm out of ideas...)

Comment: Thanks for your input! I am aware that something is using systemd-resolved (see my line above about "resolvconf / resolvectl / systemd-resolve") but I don't know what is using it. Is it Network Manager, something else?